# One function activated by two buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, button

I have two `buttons` and one `function` called 'starta' and it has `parameter` 'oi'.

My question is shouldn't the `button` with id of 'ooii' just work and not both of them ? Could somebody explain the reason both of these buttons are working ?

```js
function starta(oi) {
  document.getElementById(oi).style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
button.rond {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="np"><button style="background-color:yellow" id="y" class="rond" onclick="starta('y')">alotus</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="np"><button style="background-color:yellow" id="ooii" class="rond" onclick="starta('ooii')">alotus</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `oi` is a variable and has no relation to the string or element with the id `"ooii"`, in spite of the (kind of) similarity. Why not add `console.log(oi)` just above `document.getElementById`? Then, try changing `oi` to `adhajsdasgdasgdh` and see if it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are doing is , you are giving your `function` a `parameter` "oi"

```
        function starta(oi)
```

Then You you use that `parameter` as **id**:

```
        document.getElementById(oi)
```

Then you pass your function the value (`argument`) of the id of the actual button clicked and it becomes the parameter

```
        onclick="starta('ooii')"
        onclick="starta('y')
```

That basically means that you use the id "ooii" and "y" as your argument/value for your parameter.

if you click "y" your function looks like this:

```
function starta(y) {
document.getElementById(y).style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
```

If you click "ooii" your function looks like this:

```
function starta(ooii) {
document.getElementById(ooii).style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT:**

If you want only one button to work do:

```
 function starta() {
   document.getElementById("ooii").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
```

IN HTML:

```
onclick="starta()"
```

Comment: thank you for good answers, should parameter name in function be same as getElementById(this one here ?), i mean why this is not working here : function starta(oi) { document.getElementById(kj).style.backgroundColor = "green"; } <td class="np"><button style="background-color:yellow" id="kj" class="rond" onclick="starta('ooii')">alotus</button></td></tr> ? sory if its not straightly related question

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be the same, but in your case if you want both buttons to work then yes. If you give the document.getElmentById() a undefined argument(kj) then this can obviously not work because there is no id="kj" and the argument passed is defined with "oi". Hope this makes sense for you.

Comment: i mean why here i have put different name but dont work : <table >
 <tr>
   <td class="np"><button style="background-color:yellow" id="kj" class="rond" onclick="starta('ooii')">alotus</button></td></tr>
  </table></div>

<script>

 function starta(oi) {
       document.getElementById(kj).style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


</script>

Comment: you have to put "kj" into quotation marks: document.getElementById("kj")

Answer (score 1):

When you click the first button, `starta` is called with `'y'` as the argument.

So `starta` finds the element with id equal to `'y'` (it's the button you just pressed) and makes it green.

When you press the other button, it's the same thing but with with `'ooii'` as the argument, so THAT button becomes green.

---

Edit: About your comment... Let's say you have this function:

```
function printThisArgument(myVariable) {
  console.log(myVariable);
}
```

When you do `printThisArgument('hello')`, the function will be called and its argument (`myVariable`) will have the value `'hello'`, so it will print "hello".

The name of the variable is irrelevant.

Comment: thank you for good answer one more related to this, should parameter name in function be same as getElementById(this one here ?), i mean why this is not working here :  function starta(oi) {
       document.getElementById(kj).style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
   <td class="np"><button style="background-color:yellow" id="kj" class="rond" onclick="starta('ooii')">alotus</button></td></tr>
? sory if its not straightly related question.

Comment: @waleedd32 Your `kj` variable is not defined. The `starta` function's argument is named `oi`, and pressing the button calls the function with `oi = 'ooii'`. You shouldn't change `getElementById`, but you should change the button's `onclick` to call `starta` with `'kj'` as the argument value, instead of `'ooii'`, like that: `onclick="starta('kj')"`.

Comment: @waleedd32 To understand it easier, in your function change `oi` into `theIdToMakeGreen`.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not clear what your intent was, your code works correctly as written.

The two buttons are independent, and when you click either one, the attached function runs and makes the background green.  It happens to be the same function, and the parameter "oi" is closer to one name than the other, but that doesn't matter.